# Api is calling every time

Tags: android, web-services, android-fragments

I am new to android,

My Question is :- i use api and dispaly it's responce,

But when i come again to that page api call again.

How to solve this.

My code for this is :

```
public class SearchScreenFragment extends Fragment implements KeyListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        variable.ASC_desc="DESC";
        variable.order="ASC";

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_screen,container, false);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        if(bundle != null){
            search=getArguments().getString("search").trim();  
            variable.searchString=search;
        }
     SearchJob(search);  // Api calling
             }

    }
}
```

private void SearchJob(String text){

```
String link="http: // Url to send 


        Log.d("History ", link);

        task=new Async();
        task.execute(link);


    }
```

}

Url which i send is sometimes change and sometime it was same as pervious one, so how to solve this issue.

I am confuse.

Please help me to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the API `SearchJob(search);` is called every time you 'open' the `SearchScreenFragment` because `onCreateView` is called every time this Fragment is 'opened'.

The best solution, in my opinion, would be to cache/store the response of this API somewhere in memory (for example, in an SQLite database or in SharedPreferences) and fetch it locally instead of calling this API again.

Pseudocode:

```
if(searchResultsAreStored()) {
     getStoredResults();
} else {
     SearchJob(search);  // Api calling
}
```

Comment: It halp me, but sometimes my url is change and some times not, so how to do this,Please help me